# String Concatenation in a for loop causing app to stall - Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I have an app i am building that is at this particular point building a string in C# to return to my WebView. Simple Concatenation works perfectly but when I do so in a for loop it stalls. This loop runs anywhere from 30-40 times. Something I had read recommended using a `StringBuilder` inside a loop but this didn't help. My code looks like this:

```
        StringBuilder jsonReturn = new StringBuilder();
        jsonReturn.Append("{");
        for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count(); i++)
        {
            jsonReturn.Append("fooBar");
        }
        jsonReturn.Append("}");
        return jsonReturn.ToString();
```

If I comment out the line inside the for loop it runs perfectly. Any ideas?

Comment: what specifically do you mean by "stall"?

Comment: I suppose that you have simplified a lot your code because this is in no way a valid json string

Comment: @Jason it freezes and eventually crashes with no error.

Comment: @Steve Yes, when it wasn't working I simplified the code to attempt to figure out what is going on. Once this issue is resolved I can properly build the JSON.

Comment: @Xandor `eventually crashes` ? There will be an error somewhere, check the `logcat` output...

Comment: @SushiHangover I believe the official error is a timeout but given the simple coding it seems like something else is going wrong. I had to step away from my laptop but when I get back I will check the logcat.

Comment: @SushiHangover I guess I'm still getting used to Visual Studios/Xamarin. You pointed me in the right direction, The crash wasn't happening on the C# side. The string was making it back into the WebView just fine, but the returned string was too long for how my JavaScript was handling. Just had to make some minor tweaks.

Comment: @Xandor glad you found it.

Answer (score 2):

> I believe the official error is a timeout

If it is a ANR (Android Not Responding) *type of problem*, move your string processing off the main/UI thread, a `Task.Run` to place that work on a thread will work:

```
StringBuilder jsonReturn = new StringBuilder();
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    jsonReturn.Append("{");
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count(); i++)
    {
        jsonReturn.Append("fooBar");
    }
    jsonReturn.Append("}");
});
return jsonReturn.ToString();
```